# Python: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web, web-scraping

Here is my code: I tried to read a web page and select few html items for further processing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('http://www.iceomatic.com/Products/Ice-Machines/Cubers/')
icesoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.read())
selectElems = icesoup.select('li')
len(selectElems)
type(selectElems[0])
selectElems[0].click()
```

And it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "web.py.txt", line 18, in <module>
icesoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.read())
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of 
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0000028FA783A0B8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
File "C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 139, in stop
File "C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 110, in 
send_remote_shutdown_command
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `res.text` instead. The `read()` attribute doesn't exist in the `Response` object.